# rabbitmq pika don't take more than one job when using a thread

Tags: rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I have a problem of `ConnectionResetError` when I block the IOLoop that `channel.start_consuming()` is running for a long time.   So I've read this code:
https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.12.0/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py
In this code the job is running in a background thread.

The problem is, when my job is running in a thread, The worker can still take more jobs, (i.e, keep getting on_message callbacks).  But I don't want my worker to process more than one job at a time.
What should I do?  Is it possible to inform the queue that the worker is 'busy' and can't accept jobs for some time?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are setting the channel's QoS value via the [`channel.basic_qos`](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/0.12.0/examples/basic_consumer_threaded.py#L50-L53) method, your consumer will not get more unacknowledged messages than specified by `prefetch_count`.

If you use the `prefetch_count=1` argument, your consumer will only get one message at a time and will not get more until `basic_ack` is called for that message.

If, for some reason, you see something different, share *all* of your code as an attachment or link in a message on the [`pika-python`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pika-python) mailing list and I will check it out.

Comment: I have a fairly long job, so I usually get disconnected. I read I should not disable heartbeats. So if I understand you correctly, I should set prefetch_count=1, perform my long job in a thread, and then ack the message? Because now I ack the message immediately as it arrives, since I'm not sure if it's ok to leave a message unacked for a long time

Comment: The example code to which you linked shows **exactly** what you should do. Did you read the code?